# needrestart keeps asking for rebooting on new kernel

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, upgrade

I have removed obsolete kernel after new kernel was installed. Now I keep getting following message from `needrestart` over and over again:

`The currently running kernel version is 4.9.0-16-amd64 and there is an ABI compatible upgrade pending.`

Several restarts of the box did not help with this. How can I fix this?

OS: Debian 9.13

Answer (score 1):

If you tried apt-get upgrade and it says

```
The following packages have been kept back:
linux-image-amd64
```

then you need to
`apt-get install linux-image-amd64` as root/with sudo.

The message should stop talking about API and start abut restarting) and THEN restart.

Comment: I believe due debian 9 is now EOL and afterwards 2 years I think it's fixed ;l

Comment: I don't think so, it's happening in newer versions as well. Sure, with different kernel version.

Comment: try running apt some v for more verbose output it sounds like the package has been pinned